# Thread cannot modify layout

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

In an `onCreate()` method I have the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    setupGui();
    mHandler = new Handler();

    mv = new MapView();
    (new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                          mv.createPlane(true);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Where mv is the name of the class I am in, which contains a `createPlane(boolean)` method for placing some new elements onto the UI. This method:

```
public void createPlane(boolean left) {
    linL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
}
```

And this does not work. (`NullPointerException` at `findViewById()`)

Comment: post the createPlane method, se we can help you

Comment: @vspallas After checking where exactly does the problem step up, this line was the one with the problem, so I see no reason to post the other several hundreds of lines. After this it stops working immediately.

Comment: @L.Bajczi please post the version of the code that worked. the shortest possible example. Otherwise, I can't help you any more than what I posted.

Comment: It is either a problem with layout inflation (cant find a view in inflated layout) or you are modifying the UI from a thread other than UI thread, which is forbidden. In the second case, use runOnUIThread method for lines where you modify the UI to fix problems

Comment: what are you trying to do to the linL? add a child or something else that needs the UiThread?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the problem is with your order of things. You have to inflate the view before trying to find a view in that view by ID. You're trying to `findViewById` before you've inflated anything! All you have is the `MapView` object.

You need to ensure that before you run the thread, the view that contains `R.id.ll` is inflated.

Comment: It's right after setContentView(R.layout.mapview); which does include this element.

Comment: @L.Bajczi before I continue to help, please add more code - a complete, short working set of code. OTherwise, it'll be a game of cat and mouse where I guess and you confirm or deny, and that doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope this way it's understandable. Sorry.

Comment: @L.Bajczi yes - you are calling mv.makePlane() - mv is a specific instance of MapView. I don't think that it has been inflated yet. The problem may also be Vladimir's comment on your question. Explore that path as well.